# Make Text Selectable using the Mouse

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, android-compose-textfield, jetbrains-compose

I want to make the `Text` selectable using the mouse similar to the `TextField`.

```
SelectionContainer {
  Text(
    text = "Some very long text which can be selected by Mouse Left Press and drag to the right.",
    maxLines = 1,
    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
  )
}
```

It works but when I try to select the entire content, by moving the mouse to the right edge of the text, it doesn't scroll the text automatically, similar to what a `TextField` would do.

Using a `TextField` works perfectly but its initial state is: Text scrolled horizontally to the end. Instead I want it to display the start.

```
TextField(
  value = "Some very long text which can be selected by Mouse Left Press and drag to the right.",
  maxLines = 1,
  singleLine = true,
  readOnly = true,
  onValueChange = {},
)
```

I can achieve what I want using `Modifier.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState(0))` but then  it breaks the text selection. I can only select the visible text using the mouse. It doesn't scroll automatically the text field when selecting with the mouse.

Comment: Just tried your second example - text stays at the start for me. And can easily select by moving mouse to the right edge.

Comment: @KirylTkach Set the text field to have a limited width, and then set the initial text to exceed the available field width to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

What worked was to set the `selection = TextRange.Zero`:

```
var textFieldValue by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) {
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(text = text, selection = TextRange.Zero))
}

BasicTextField(
    value = textFieldValue,
    textStyle = textStyle.copy(
      color = LocalContentColor.current,
    ),
    onValueChange = {},
    readOnly = true,
}
```